# How to find the magnitude of discrete Fourier transform?

Tags: python, signal-processing, dft

Is there a built in function in python to find the magnitude of DFT? (Not using `abs` function). I can't seem to find much information on the internet. Please advise.

Comment: What's wrong with `abs`?

Comment: You do not find much information because it seems like you do not get what the amplitude of DFT is, or your question is unclear, at the very least. From [Numpy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.fft.html#implementation-details) you can see that `abs(signal)` gives the signal amplitude spectrum and `abs(signal)**2` gives the signal power spectrum. What else do you want?